# Scale rounded image on hover

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to have a 'circular' image with a border, when the user hovers over the image the image inside is the border is scaled. Why does it appear to be glitching? can someone tell me whats going on?

HTML

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <div class="portfolio-item-preview">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aLJnBtV.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
    padding: 8px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.portfolio-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.portfolio-item-preview {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-item-preview {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/do5q87hq/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Border-radius is not an animatable property, so it doesn't scale with the image. It only gets scaled when the transition  ends. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-

Comment: So how could i achieve the effect?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the border while scaling, then you can position a transparent circle with a border and box shadow (box shadow will act as the actual grey border) over the image. This way you basically have a little window showing the image.

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;    

}

#circle{
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;    
    border-radius:50%;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:20px solid white;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px #666;
}
img {
    border-radius:50%;
    width:200px;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;  
}
#container:hover img{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a05or1uw/

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the border-radius on the item that `scale`:

```
.portfolio-item-preview {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Check this **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/do5q87hq/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle based on user3765149's answer.

I added a border element that can be dimensioned independently of the image scaling, while the circle element acts only as a mask. It just needs a little math to adjust it correctly.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="border"> </div>
    <div id="circle"> </div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aLJnBtV.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;    
}
#border{
    z-index:3;  
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    left:6px;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:206px;
    width:206px;
    border:1px solid #dedede;    
}
#circle{
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;    
    border-radius:50%;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:10px solid white;
}
img {
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px; 
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
}
#container:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.08);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isaacalves/dwpy4sm7/2/

Answer (score -1):

add in css "portfolio-item":

```
translateZ(0);
```

I made some changes: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/do5q87hq/18/)

:)

Comment: Consider adding more details about why the problem is happening and why this fixes the issue. This kind of answer isn't very helpful to future users but a more in depth answer can be helpful for years to come.